# Expected expression, got '<' when I want to write HTML

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, error, html, modern-experience

I am using Modern Script Editor on my SharePoint Online page and I want to put some HTML text on it (which is now a JSON object in the console).

But I want to start with a hardcoded string.

This is what I have now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divg = document.createElement("div");
    divg.appendChild(document.createTextNode("New DIV"));
    document.body.appendChild(divg);
});
```

However, nothing is being printed on the page.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you embed the code? Have you used a Script Editor Web Part / Content Editor Web Part for?

Comment: I am using the Modern Script Editor web part

Answer (score 0):

Try Using below code:

```
<div id="testDiv"> &nbsp; </div>

<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var str = '<p>Just some <span>text</span> here</p>';
        $('#testDiv').append(str);
    });
</script>
```

As you are already using `$(document).ready()`, I believe you have loaded jQuery file in your SharePoint page. If not then you can add it like below for testing your above code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: still receiving the error exptected expression, got '<', (pointing at the start of '<div id=' )

Comment: Try using updated code. It is working for me. If it is not working for you then there is some issue with your Modern Script Editor.

Comment: can you take a look at my updated question?

Comment: Is the code from my answer is working? Is the code from your updated answer is also throwing an error?

Comment: no the code that you gave threw the same error. (exptected expression, got '<') while pointing to the html tag <div id="testDiv">

Comment: and my updated code does not give an error . It just doesnt show the div that i want to see

Comment: I guess there is problem with your Modern script editor. because the both codes are working file for me. If you want I can provide you the `.sppkg` file of modern script editor which is working fine for me (you can get my email from profile).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the code below to check if it works. Edit the modern page and add the code into modern script editor web part and click "Republish", and "Ctrl+F5" to refresh the page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jq = $.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function() {
    jq("#mytest").append("<span>Test</span>");
});
</script>
<div id="mytest"/>
```

[image]

If still not works, I suggest you re-install the modern script editor web part from here:

[react-script-editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor)